# Recurrence relations and eliminating the complex numbers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I want to solve the following recurrence relation, But I can't get rid of the complex numbers appearing.

> $a_n - 2a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2} = 0, a_0 =1, a_1 = 2$

First, I let $a_n = cr^n$, then I find the characteristic equation that is $r^2-2r +2 = 0$ Now this is the same as $(r-1)^2 + 1 = 0$ and so we have two complex roots $r=1-i,1+i$

So $a_n = A(1-i)^r + B(1+i)^n$. Now I convert these two complex numbers two polar coordinates because they are easier to work with and so $$1-i = \sqrt{2}(\cos(\frac{-\pi}{4}) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}))$$ and $$1+i =\sqrt{2}(\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}))$$

Now I have that $$a_n=A(\sqrt{2}(\cos(\frac{-\pi}{4}) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}))^r + B\sqrt{2}(\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}))^r$$

Which is $$\sqrt{2}^nA(\cos(\frac{-\pi}{4}) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}))^r + \sqrt{2}^nB(\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}))^r$$

But Now I get stuck on how to find $A$ and $B$, ... I don't know how to tackle it here.

Comment: To find $A$ and $B$ you need to know two elements of the sequence to start the recurrence for instance $a_0$ and $a_1$

Comment: @marwalix yes I included them

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The general solution can be written

$$a_n=(A\cos(n\frac\pi4)+B\sin(n\frac\pi4))\sqrt2^n.$$

Plugging the initial conditions, you get

$$a_0=A=1.$$

$$a_1=(\frac A{\sqrt2}+\frac B{\sqrt2})\sqrt2=2.$$

Comment: I edited my solution, and I tried to follow your hint but how did u get that $a_n=(A\cos(n\frac\pi4)+B\sin(n\frac\pi4))\sqrt2^n$ and how the imaginary $i$ disappeared ??

Comment: Think the reverse way. As the recurrence equation and initial values are real, all terms must be real, there can be no $i$.